# Why did my improvement to an edit create a suggested edit to revert it?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I just improved an edit by changing one word [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5802).

Immediately afterwards, I see [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5803) suggested edit which appears to be suggesting to reverse my edit.

Did the following happen?

- User suggests edit
- I approve
- User changes edit again

Or why else did that happen? From my perspective it seems my improvement was rejected and then proposed as a change again.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at its [revision](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/15332/revisions), that user first suggested [this edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5802) which you edited and replaced "crack" with "make" and removed "at". Then the user again suggested [this edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5803) to replace "make" with "crack", which you rejected, but a moderator improved it. So it's a normal situation where that user suggested edit on that question twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Looking at [his suggestion history](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/3079/thesilverbullet?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) he has suggested twice on the same question.

Comment: @MartinSmith no, those are clearly two different suggestions, each with its own ID and posted three minutes from each other. The editor simply noticed his edit changed and changed it back.

Comment: Yes I agree. The repetition of the same edit comment made me think there might be something else at play.

Comment: Is there a good way to actually tell that user why I rejected it (other than reject reason)? I guess I could ping him in chat, though as a non-mod I can't super ping him

Comment: @enderland - nope. Only options are either on chat or on any of his post...